# How to fix/hide `Unable to enumarate family warning` in pyqt5?

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt5, warnings

Each time I run my python script I'm facing this warning:

`qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to enumerate family`

What can be the cause of this warning? How do I fix this warning? If this warning can't be fixed, how can this hide or silenced?

**Edit:**
I've tried to install all the fonts in the warning but it still persists.

The warning is on the left side of the picture and the list of fonts installed in my Windows 10 system is on the right side.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong! The fonts listed in the warning are somehow incompatible with PyQt5, so I just need to delete them. [This is the link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127007-delete-uninstall-fonts-windows-10-a.html) on how to delete fonts in Windows 10 *(From [www.tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com))*.

1. Press the <kbd>Win+R</kbd> keys to open Run, type regedit into Run, and click/tap on OK to open Registry Editor.
2. Navigate to the key below in the left pane of Registry Editor. (see screenshot below)
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
   [image]
3. In the right pane of the Fonts key, right click on the string value for the font (ex: "Agency FB Bold (TrueType)") you want to delete, and click/tap on <kbd>Delete</kbd>. (see screenshot above)

> Be sure to make note of the font file name (ex: "AGENCYB.TTF") you are deleting before you delete the string value.

4. Click/tap on Yes to confirm. (see screenshot below)
   [image: Delete and Uninstall Fonts in Windows 10-confirm_delete_font_in_regedit.png]
5. When finished deleting fonts, close Registry Editor.
6. Sign out and sign in again to the same account.
7. Open File Explorer (<kbd>Win+E</kbd>).
8. Copy and paste `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` into the address bar of File Explorer, and press Enter.
9. Delete the same font(s) (ex: "AGENCYB.TTF") referenced from step 3 above. (see screenshot below)
   [image: Delete and Uninstall Fonts in Windows 10-delete_font_for_current_user_in_regedit-2.jpg]
10. You can now close File Explorer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Warning is just a hint for the developer, not an error.
You can hide this warning with:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Im not sure about this warning but i think this warning often occurs when PyQt5 cannot find any fonts in your system.

Most often it means that you don't have fonts installed on your system.
So, try to install them.

Most often fonts are installed in /usr/share/fonts directory.
You can install fonts by using command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

If you are using other distribution, you can search for similar command and install fonts.

Comment: I've tried to install all the fonts in the warning on my Windows 10 machine but the error still persists.